# How to access custom date field inside the subquery?

Tags: subquery

I am unable to retrieve one custom date field  which I created in the custom object which I have coded inside my sub query.

The date field is visit_date__c inside the custom object Location__c in subquery.

```
list<person__c> locationTracing = ([SELECT Id, Name, Mobile_No__c, Token__c, 
                                   Health_Status__c, Visited_Locations__c,
                                   (SELECT Name, personid__c, Visit_date__c, 
                                   Location__c FROM PersonIds__r)  
                                   FROM Person__c WHERE Id IN :personids]);

list<person__c> ReturnRecs = new list<person__c>();

For(person__c LocationRecs : locationTracing) {

date VisitDate = LocationRecs.Visit_date__c;
```

I am getting an error message in the developer console that the field **visit_date__c is not available**, eventhough that date field is very much available in the Location object.

If I try like this

```
date VisitDate = LocationRecs.PersonIds__r.Visit_date__c;
```

Then this error message pops up '**A non foreign key field cannot be referenced in a path expression: PersonIds__r**

I want to successfully access the visit_date__c field.

Someone Please Help!!!

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop through the parent and child records to get access to the child field such as :

```
for(Person__c person : locationTracing) {
    for(Location__c locationRec : person.PersonIds__r) {
        System.debug(locationRec.Visit_date__c);
    }
}
```